# Fetching data from background

Tags: ios, multithreading, background, grand-central-dispatch, fetch

Well,
I haven't found the right answer yet, regarding this scenario:
There is an app which fetches some data from a webpage. There is ability to refresh data manually or automatically via NSTimer. All is ok if it is happening while the app is in foreground / active. My question is there possibility to still have updated/refreshed data after pressing home button. I am asking it because I have to implement automatic refresh in background which will trigger notification based on refreshed data from background. 
I read some material about gcd, but there is no strict distinction between background (in manner of separate thread) or background (in manner of real background - the app is not visible), so I am little confused..

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to perform tasks in the background permanently at the interval of time you are requesting. You may request specific permission via the developer connection but I must warn you that you will need a very compelling argument. I included the documentation below, maybe your request falls within one of the groupings that could run permanently. Or maybe you could use one of the long running background threads and adapt it in such a way that it fulfils the task you are attempting.

[Documentation](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_ios_backgrounding_techniques/ios_backgrounding_with_tasks/)